# Why is the mirror descent considered a "non-Euclidean" algorithm?

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, noneuclidean-geometry

I am perplexed by the fact that many sources online such as this website refer to [mirror descent as a non-Euclidean](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs229t/Lectures/mirror-descent.pdf) gradient descent.

[image]

Why non-Euclidean?

1. The constraint set $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is perfectly Euclidean.
2. The vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, g_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ both live in the Euclidean space.
3. $D_h(x,x_k)$ is not a Euclidean norm, in fact, not any norm, not any metric either, even if we refer to it as a "[distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics))", it is a distance on what set/space?  I would not refer to $D_h$ as a non-Euclidean distance, it is not a distance at all.

I expected that when talking about "non-Euclidean gradient descent", we meant that we will equip a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with some [non-Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm), such as $\|\cdot\|_1$, and performs minimization on that space. But it seems that we are still performing minimization on the Euclidean space. Even the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the standard ["Euclidean" dot product](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-euclidean-inner-product), which induces the Euclidean norm. Why non-Euclidean?

Can someone please clarify as to what "non-Euclidean" mean in this context?

Comment: The [first link](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~lienart/blog_opti_mda.html) while googling has the answer. See the passing from (3) to (4), and the line before the yellow box enclosing (4).

Comment: @sunwarm Thanks, the key problem for me was "non-Euclidean" but in what sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One comment is that the projected gradient descent iteration can be expressed as $$
x_{k+1} = \arg \min_{x \in C} \quad f(x_k) + \langle \nabla f(x_k),x - x_k \rangle + \frac{1}{2t} \|x - x_k \|_2^2.
$$ Omitting terms that don't depend on $x$, we have 
$$
x_{k+1} = \arg \min_{x \in C} \quad \langle \nabla f(x_k), x \rangle + \frac{1}{2t} \|x - x_k \|_2^2.
$$ 
This looks quite like the Mirror descent iteration given, except that the Euclidean distance $\| x - x_k \|_2$ has been replaced by the "non-Euclidean distance" $D_h(x,x_k)$. You might object that $D_h$ is not a metric, which is a valid point -- I think they are just speaking loosely.

"[One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296)." -- Richard Feynman

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer. I think the naming is indeed confusing, especially when you constrast it against optimization on Riemannian manifolds such as http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2015/04/4881.pdf .

Comment: @ElCamino I'm glad you pointed out that paper, it looks interesting.